# VSCode Not showing ColorPicker

Tags: visual-studio-code

i searched that VSCode have built-in ColorPicker from this [Link](https://mspoweruser.com/visual-studio-code-now-really-useful-color-picker-built/)

But i'm trying to learn code igniter with vscode and there's nothing like that. How to enable it ? i tried to enable `editor.colorDecorators:true` but its doesn't change anything.

[image: vscode]

Comment: I had to install it again. Of course, this time I installed VSCode Insider and problem solved.

Comment: this is CSS block inside an HTML block in a PHP file, try a single CSS file or CSS inside an HTML file

Comment: Is the color hover feature available with regular Visual Studio (not "Code")? I thought I saw it pop-up on rare occasions, but can't recreate it.

Answer (score 8):

Go to settings, the small cog in the bottom left of the screen.

[image]

Type in '**hover**' into the settings search bar and make sure '**Editor>Hover:Enabled**' is checked

[image]

Now when you hover a color, the color picker should appear

If you are not seeing the color box, check CSS is selected as the language in the bottom right, if it is not, click on it and select CSS.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

When I had that same problem it was because I had "editor.hover.enabled": false, in my VS Code settings and setting it to true got the color picker working.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue the language mode is selected to postcss and not css. When I set to css the color picker boxes appeared again.

[image: There are no color picker boxes when the language is set to postcss.]

[image: It's appearing when the language is set (back) to css.]

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255)
}
```

then hover over 'rgb'

edit:

I've just noticed it also works for `#fff`, but you need to lose the quotes

Comment: nothing shown, should i change or edit some setting on vscode preference ?

Comment: it is probably because you are editing a file with a PHP extension. The picker is only enabled for HTML, CSS, Sass, LESS files.

Answer (score 2):

CSS-in-JS is popular nowadays, use [vscode-color-picker](https://github.com/antiantisepticeye/vscode-color-picker#what-are-the-languages-i-can-add-to-the-extension) to bring the color picker to files other than css/sass/less (the built-in color picker supports styling files only, for now)

After installation, add the languages list to the settings because the extension does not turn on the feature by default.

on Mac: press `Command` + `Shift` + `P` then choose **Open User Settings (JSON)**

Then add these settings:

```
  "vscode-color-picker.languages": [
    "php",
    "html",
    "css",
    "rust",
    "python",
    "json",
    "jsonc",
    "yaml",
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact",
    "vue",
    "vue-html"
  ]
```

As I tested:

- It does not work with `.tsx` file (although it is in the list of the [supported languages](https://github.com/antiantisepticeye/vscode-color-picker#what-are-the-languages-i-can-add-to-the-extension))
- Works well with `.js` and `.ts`.

Answer (score 1):

Note there is an issue which can explain the lack of color picker, for large files (typically more than 500 lines).

[#139743: "Built-in color picker stops working on large css files"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139743).

This is fixed by [commit c0aa5bb](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/c0aa5bbb84738d7d1a1e9781b61eee1806b2605f) and available in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) today, to be released with VSCode 1.75 (Jan. 2023).

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do any settings, just remove the double quotes from the color (from `"#fff"` to `#fff`).

If that doesn't work out then use these extension, I prefer it to the VS Code picker:

[image]