# Color picker not showing in VS Code but only for CSS files

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, ide, postcss

I started looking for React development stuff and I came across something I wanted to try and started working on a project, but when I ran the command `npx create-react-app my_app_name` my CSS color picker stopped showing up in the index.css file, and I tried another projects I have been working on previously where I remember using the color picker, and it still didn't work.

Another weird thing is that I can see that html file has that enabled and it works perfectly, but in CSS it doesn't I tried everything on the internet, but nothing worked, any possible way that react changed my settings in the process and disabled something? is there a solution for this?

Comment: This seems to be an IDE issue and not related to any of the tags you added. What IDE are you using?

Comment: @Dominik He's using VS Code, it's in the title. This question doesn't belong here

Comment: Oh yeah missed the title. Yeah not the right place to ask this

Comment: what do you guys mean, people ask this kind of questions. here similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530586/vscode-not-showing-colorpicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok if anyone stumbles across this, it might help.

After uninstalling VSCode Completely, and installing it again it started working again, and what my initial problem was that I had installed PostCSS Language Support, which upon installing it before I had no problem, but with probably in latest patch, I got the problem where the picker and also the suggestions were deleted/disabled by VSCode.

If you have PostCSS Language Support, just disable it, and everything should work perfectly.