# VS Code stopped suddenly from previewing colors in settings.json file how to fix that?

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code, text-editor

Someone asked a similar questions but non of the answers fixed the issue:
[The questions on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530586/vscode-not-showing-colorpicker)

also here is a link to the feature I am referring to :
[VSCode color picker feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTpvq.png)

P.S.
it doesn't work on SOME .json files only with like settings.json.

Comment: if the JSON scheme does not mark this field as a color you don't get a color decoration

Comment: @rioV8 it was working fine, it just suddenly stopped working.

Comment: if the decorator provider who has previously supplied the decorator for this file has removed it in an update you don't get it anymore

Comment: @rioV8 do I know if that is the case? and is there a way to add it back?

Comment: do you still get this decorator in `settings.json` for the theme customisations

Comment: @rioV8 yes actually, but it isn't working for other settings like ( "borderColor": "#ffffff",) inside an extension settings, but it use to work before.

Comment: in the json scheme of the extension you can mark a setting as a color, check the extension `package.json`

Comment: @rioV8 there is no color json scheme in the package.json, any idea how to do it?

Comment: which extension

Comment: "rioV8 Bracket Pair Colorizer & Highlight Matching Tag

Comment: `Bracket Pair Colorizer` does not have JSON configuration scheme in `package.josn`, `Highlight Matching Tag` has JSON configuration scheme but the color entries are not marked as being a color so no color decoration, create an issue if needed